# How do I issue multiple certificates for the same Common Name?

Tags: ssl-certificate, openssl, certificate, certificate-authority, pki

I am creating a Certificate Authority for an intranet.

I have generated a root and intermediate CA and successfully signed a server certificate using the intermediate CA. The server certificate has `CN=mysite.com`.

In the future this server certificate will expire and I will need to issue a new one. However, if I create another CSR with the same `CN=mysite.com` then when I sign it I get

```
failed to update database
TXT_DB error number 2
```

This error goes away if I create a new CSR with a different CN, but the CNs have to be the same or the browser won't say it's valid, right?

How do I fix this?

EDIT: I'm following [this guide](https://jamielinux.com/docs/openssl-certificate-authority/sign-server-and-client-certificates.html) -- everything's fine up until the end of the linked page, but when I try to repeat the steps on this page to create a *second* certificate, openssl demands that I give the new certificate a different CN.

```
SUBJ="/C=$C/ST=$ST/L=$L/O=$O/OU=$OU/CN=$CN"

# Generate CSR
echo "$PW" | openssl req \
    -config "$CAROOT/intermediate/openssl.cnf" \
    -new -sha256 -subj "$SUBJ" -passin stdin \
    -key "$PRIV_ENC" -out "$CSR_INT" >/dev/null 2>&1 ||
{
    >&2 echo "Could not openssl req";
    exit 1;
}

# Sign CSR
openssl ca \
    -config "$CAROOT/intermediate/openssl.cnf" \
    -batch -extensions server_cert \
    -days "$HTTP_DAYS" -notext -md sha256 \
    -in "$CSR_INT" -out "$CRT_INT" ||
{
    >&2 echo "Could not openssl ca";
    exit 1;
}
```

It's the `openssl ca` which fails.

Comment: Can you please elaborate your process? It seems like you are doing it all wrong

Comment: @Orphans I edited it to link more info.

Comment: If you are using openssl via the cli, can you include the actually command line you are using that results in the error condition?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Do you need dupes?** Traditionally browsers and clients required that the CommonName *field* of the Subject name match the hostname; modern ones prefer that an entry in the SubjectAlternativeName (SAN) *extension* do so. You can set *other* fields to differ e.g.

```
O=Floo Manufacturing, OU=floo server 2016, CN=www.floo.example.com
O=Floo Manufacturing, OU=floo server 2017, CN=www.floo.example.com
```

and the Subject DNs are unique even though CommonName by itself is not.
Or with modern clients you *could* put `www.floo.example.com` in SAN and use unique Subjects with no CommonName at all. But getting openssl to do per-cert SAN is a bit inconvenient; see e.g. https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/113484/followup-to-one-liner-to-create-cert-request-with-san

To allow dupes: **the official way**

**In your config file** (which is `$CAROOT/intermediate/openssl.cnf`) go to the 'section' (delimited by lines of the form `[somename]` with optional whitespace) **for your CA**. Since you didn't use `-name` on the commandline the section name is the value of `default_ca` in the `[ca]` section or the default section (at the top before the first `[somename]` line); looking near your link it's probably `[CA_default]`. Add a line

```
 unique_subject=no
```

with spacing and following `# comment` optional. Or if you already have a line for this item change and/or uncomment it, but looking near your link you probably don't.

See man page `ca(1ssl)` on your system or [the web](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man1/ca.html#CONFIGURATION-FILE-OPTIONS) under CONFIGURATION FILE OPTIONS.

To allow dupes: **the unofficial way**

**Empty** (truncate) the configured `database` file which is conventionally **`index.txt`** and looking near your link they apparently use that. **Or** edit that file and **delete the line(s)** for the subject(s) you want to re-use -- but in this situation it looks like you have only one or a few and you want to re-use it or all of them, so emptying the file is simpler.

Comment: TL;DR -- change `OU` to some variation.

Comment: Given that certs expire more often than CAs, what is the "proper" way to reissue a cert when it expires or is about to expire?

Comment: @kbolino: depending on how or for what they are used, I would say either tweaking Subject or setting unique_subject=no could be proper.

Answer (score 12):

If you want to create multiple certificates with the same subject, you can change your configuration like that:

You can change in the CA section (probably `[CA_default]`) in your `openssl.cnf` the setting

```
unique_subject = no
```

But this setting is also saved in file `index.txt.attr`, you have to change this, too. Otherwise it will not work.

Comment: Although less detailed, this answer was more helpful due to it mention of the index.txt.attr file.

Comment: for me i just needed to change the `index.txt.attr` file and no settings in `openssl.cnf`